# Why is the Torah (itself) called an inheritance?

Tags: torah-study, chabad, chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe

My question concerns the [Maamer "Torah Tziva" (ה'תשכ"ג)](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/mlukat/1/27/index.htm). (try to read at least the first 3 paragraphs, since that's what my question is on)

> תורה צוה לנו משה מורשה קהלת יעקב1, שהתורה היא ירושה2 לכאו"א3 שמקהלת
> יעקב. וידועים הדיוקים בזה4, הרי אמרו רז"ל5 התקן עצמך ללמוד תורה שאינה
> ירושה לך, וכאן נאמר שהתורה היא ירושה. גם צריך להבין, דפירוש ירושה
> בפשטות הוא שיורש מאבותיו (היינו שמצד עצמו אינו שייך להדבר אלא שירש זה
> מאבותיו), והרי כל ישראל היו (נשמותיהם) במעמד הר סיני6 וקיבלו בעצמם את
> התורה. גם צריך להבין, דבפסוק שלאח"ז7 נאמר ויהי בישורון מלך בהתאסף ראשי
> עם יחד שבטי ישראל, מהי השייכות דויהי בישורון מלך גו' למורשה קהלת יעקב.
> גם, דבפסוק זה נקראים ישראל בשם יעקב (מורשה קהלת יעקב), ובהפסוק שלאח"ז
> בתחלתו נקראים בשם ישורון (ויהי בישורון מלך) ובסיום הפסוק נקראים בשם
> ישראל (יחד שבטי ישראל).
>
> ב) ונקודת הביאור בזה (כמובן מהדרושים8), דבתורה שני ענינים. התורה כמו
> שהיא מצד עצמה, שהיא חכמתו ורצונו של הקב"ה, וכמו שהתורה ירדה למטה,
> ומבררת ומזככת את העולם, מתחיל מהבירור והזיכוך שבאדם הלומד, שהשכל דנפש
> הבהמית מתברר ומזדכך ונכלל בקדושה9. וזהו10 שאמרו רז"ל11 לעולם יעסוק אדם
> בתורה ומצוות שלא לשמה שמתוך שלא לשמה בא לשמה, דבתחילת העבודה, עסק
> התורה דהאדם הוא בכדי לברר ולזכך את נפשו, כמאמר רז"ל12 מעיקרא כי עביד
> איניש אדעתא דנפשי' קא עביד, שעסק התורה שלו הוא בכדי לזכך את נפשו,
> ועי"ז בא אח"כ לעסק התורה לשמה, לשם התורה עצמה (שלמעלה מענין הבירורים).
>
> 196 וזהו שהתורה נקראת ירושה ואעפ"כ אמרו התקן עצמך ללמוד תורה שאינה
> ירושה, דזה שהתורה נקראת ירושה הוא מצד הבירורים שע"י התורה. דהניצוצות
> שבדברים הגשמיים, וכן הניצוצות שבהשכל דנפש הבהמית, שרשם הוא בתוהו,
> והשורש דנשמות ישראל הוא בתיקון. דזהו שעשו נקרא גדול ויעקב נקרא קטן13,
> כי שורש עשו הוא בתוהו, שהאורות דתוהו הם אורות מרובים (גדול), ושורש
> יעקב הוא בתיקון, שהאורות דתיקון הם אורות מועטים וכן מוגבלים בכלים
> (קטן). וכיון שיעקב ועשו הם אחים, כמ"ש14 הלא אח עשו ליעקב, והאחים
> יורשים זה את זה, לכן, על ידי שנשמות ישראל מבררים את הניצוצות, הם
> יורשים האורות דתוהו. ומ"ש התקן עצמך ללמוד תורה שאינה ירושה לך הוא
> בנוגע להתורה כמו שהיא למעלה מענין הבירורים, דהמשכת בחינה זו דתורה היא
> על ידי לימוד התורה לשמה. וזהו התקן עצמך ללמוד תורה, שצריך לייגע עצמו
> שיהי' לימודו לשמה בלי שום פני' כלל (גם לא הפני' דלזכך את נפשו), ועל
> ידי לימוד התורה לשמה הוא ממשיך התורה כמו שהיא מצד עצמה. שדרגא זו דתורה
> היא למעלה גם מהאורות דתוהו (שישראל יורשים ע"י עבודת הבירורים), שאינה
> ירושה לך.

There it explains 2 difference reasons why the Torah is called an inheritance (2nd one not copied here), and it's the first reason that I'm having some trouble understanding.

Basically, in explaining this, he's answering a simple question: how can we say in the verse that the Torah is an "inheritance to the kahal of Yaakov" [(Devarim 33:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.33.4?ven=The_Rashi_chumash_by_Rabbi_Shraga_Silverstein&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), but in Pirkei Avos it says "you should prepare yourself (like work hard) to learn Torah, for **it is not an inheritance** to you" [(Avos 2:12)](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.2.12?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

The simple answer is that the two sources are talking about different aspects of Torah. In general, there are two dimensions of Torah: 1) How it exists in Hashem's mind only, 2) And how it descends into this world to fill it and give light/life to it etc...

So he says (in the 2nd / 3rd paragraph(s), note there) that the first step one takes in learning Torah is the part of it that he's more related to / accessable, which is the part that *descends* into this world, so its on equal standing with him and he has easy access to it.

Then, after learning that level of Torah, he says that since through learning the Torah, it gives more life to you and elevates you, so then eventually you can access the part of Torah that is in Hashem's mind only, since you have been elevated.

That's the basic idea that I got from reading it (if someone can correct me that would be great), but I'm not fully understanding the conclusion of how this answers the question. Just based on this first part, I would assume that the part of Torah that goes down into this world is an inheritance since its more related to you, (an inheritance *for the congregation of Yaakov)*, and the higher level of Torah that's united with Hashem's mind is the part of Torah that it says "prepare yourself/work to learn Torah, for it is not an inheritance", since this part of the Torah is not so related to you at first, you have to work to get it.

That's what I thought the conclusion would be based on the intro, but it's actually not (entirely, at least).

As you can see above, in the 3rd paragraph he says that the reason why the lower level is called an inheritance is because it causes you to "inherit" the "sparks of Tohu" that are in the world, since by learning Torah you elevate / fix up al the spiritual forces in the world that need fixing (sparks of Tohu), and they become transformed into holiness (Tikkun), like "inheriting", and he mentions that the orignal sparks of Tohu are like "Esav", 'cause it's very powerful and uncontrollable "big lights in small vessels" and the energy of Tikkun that it gets converted to is like Yaakov "..for he was small", and Tikkun is "small lights in big vessels"...

Anyway he explains that Yaakov and Esav are brothers, and brothers inherit each other, so when learning this lower-aspect of Torah, it *causes* you to "inherit" the sparks of Esav, and this is also what he says later in the maamer (not quoted above, but its in the link):

> ו) וצריך להבין, דלפי ביאור הנ"ל, הטעם שהתורה נקראת בשם ירושה הוא לפי
> שהתורה מביאה לירושה (שע"י הבירורים שע"י התורה יורשים אורות דתהו),
> והפירוש דתורה גו' מורשה (בפשטות, דאין מקרא יוצא מידי פשוטו47) הוא,
> שהתורה עצמה היא ירושה48.

He asks a question that according to the "simple" meaning of the verse, the Torah itself is an inheritance, while the above explanation was that the Torah only *brings* you to an inheritance.

But this was my question: what exactly *is* the non-simple explanation that says that the Torah "brings" to an inheritance, why is the Torah called an inheritance according to that explanation, since it only brings you to one?

Why is the Torah "called an inheritance" when it only brings you to an inheritance? Is it because it iteself also is accessible to you, in addition to causing you to inherit the lights of Tohu? I'm not sure.

Comment: i made a small edit that i think removes confusion in one line that you wrote. Feel free to change it again if you don't like what i did there.

Comment: @DavidKenner good catch it was a typo on my part :)

Comment: It's very confusing and not clear.  It ties in with the Baal HaTanya.

Comment: @DannyF maybe it ties in with it, but in this maamer its saying something different, look at the sources in the link, this is not ftom tanya directly. Also, the way these maamarim work is that its possible to understand it on a basic level without looking in other sources

Comment: He cites the Tanya, (footnote 9) in the link you provided. I understand your lack of clarity in the ma'amer. It is contradictory, difficult to understand, and he assumes that you have a background in what he is talking about.  I think it would be better to ask one of the Rabbis in Chabad to help you.  This is a very difficult piece to get my head into.

Comment: @DannyF its true that he quotes Tanya, but that was only to explain that even though a Beinoni can't fully transform his emotions to holiness, but they can still be elevated by learning Torah and doing Mitzvos (which is refferring to the level of learning Torah not for its OWN sake, but "for the sake or your SOUL/(self)", to refine the sparks within your own animal soul, but he doesn't mention Tanya's xplanation of learning Torah for it's own sake, also, what is seemingly contradictory? I don't see any contradictions, only that one question I Had about what is the "non-simple" meaning of verse

Comment: I'm saying to you to get someone more qualified, and you keep on asking me why?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2828026/jewish/Dvar-Torah-Questions-and-Answers-on-Berachah.htm